# How to send mail using code from Office365 when TLS is enabled?

Tags: c#, ssl, office365

My client has an account in Office365 and he recently added this account in the website he is using. Now he says that he cannot send mails using this account, whilst other accounts are OK. He says that TLS is enabled in the account. Anyhow, I am able to login to the mail account. I checked the settings and found that the SMTP settings are as follows:

Server name: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Encryption method: STARTTLS

This is a sample code that I am using to check.

```
String userName = "365useraccount";
String password = "password";
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@test.com"));
msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(userName);
msg.Subject = "Test Office 365 Account";
msg.Body = "Testing email using Office 365 account.";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = true;
try
{
    client.Send(msg);
}
catch
{
}
```

I am getting an exception with message:

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [BMXPR01CA0043.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

However, I am able to send mails using other Office365 accounts. 
Any help of idea would be greatly appreciated